# How to sort an array $A[1..i..n]$ where $A[i] \in \{1,2,..,n^5 \}$ in $\Theta (n)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, radix-sort

> I need to write a sorting algorithm which will sort an array $A[1..n]$, $1 \le i \le n$ such that $A[i] \in \{1,2,..,n^5 \}$, all numbers are positive integers in $\Theta (n)$ time.

The solution **must** use some combination of radix/counting/bucket sort and possibly select algorithm, it can't use any advanced concepts or structures.

I thought of the following:

0) Convert the numbers into base $n$.

1) Count how many digits each number of the array $A$ contains. We know that the number with max amount of digits will be $n^5$. It'll have $\lfloor{\log_b n^5} \rfloor +1= \lfloor 5\log_b n \rfloor+1$ digits, where $b$ is the base.Because we changed the base to $n$, there will be $\lfloor 5\log_n n \rfloor+1 =6$ unique digit lengths. Create an array `countArray` which will contain how many occurrences of tens, hundreds etc are.

2) Create `subArrays` which will contain numbers of the same amount of digits and run radix sort on each such subarray. Radix-Sort runs in $\Theta(d(n+b))$ in general and in our case it will become $\Theta(6(n+n)=\Theta(6n)=\Theta(n)$.

3) In the last step we copy the sorted subarrays into the output array.

Below is the pseudocode but I'm interested if my idea is correct and if the time complexity of my algorithm is $\Theta(n)$:

```
1 MySort(A, n)                    //A is the array, n is array length
2    uniqueDigitsNum <- 5log_n(n) + 1=6
3    init countArray             // the array of length uniqueDigitsNum
4    for i <- 0 to n             //O(n)
5        //B is a helper array which will store how many digits are in a given number
6        countDigits(A[i], B[i])
7        countArray[B[i]]++      //update the count of how many times we see x digits in CountArray
8    // init a 2d array which will contain uniqueDigitsNum subarrays
9    init subArrays of length uniqueDigitsNum  
10    for k <- 0 to uniqueDigitsNum  //O(6)
11        init subArrays[k] of length countArray[k]
12    for k <- 0 to uniqueDigitsNum  //O(6n)
13        Radix-Sort(subArrays[k])   //O(countArray[k])
14    //we'll need 'j' to know at which index to start copying the next subarray in the big output array
15    j <- 0                      
16    for k <- 0 to uniqueDigitsNum  //O(n)
17        for j to countArray[j]     //O(countArray[j])
18            outputArray[j] <- subArrays[k][j]
```

Comment: What is the context where you encountered this question?  Did it come from a textbook?  Can you give a full citation?  How do you know the problem is solvable?

Comment: It's an exercise given in our algorithms class. It is solvable because otherwise they wouldn't give it to us and this is the full citation

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @D.W. often times as it happens at least with me, my answer are incorrect. For example rus9384 claims that the time complexity of my algorithm is higher than linear. I think it'd be appropriate for someone to post an answer which offers the correct solution or correction of my mistakes

Comment: " I think it'd be appropriate for someone to post an answer which offers the correct solution or correction of my mistakes" -- It'd be helpful to *you*, but nobody else. Whether it's appropriate (or even legal) depends a lot on your ethics and the rules of your school.

Comment: What is the machine model here?

Comment: @Raphael what do you mean by machine model?

Comment: For instance, TM vs RAM. If RAM, uniform or logarithmic cost model? Your task may be impossible in one and trivial in the other. You may want to peruse [our reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844).

Comment: The exercise didn't mention such details

Answer (score 1):

1. Radix sort for integers of arbitrary length has $\mathcal{O}(mn)$ time complexity, where m is the length of number.
2. Count digits takes $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$ time, so, your cycle will take at least (in worst case though) $\mathcal{O}(n \log(n))$ time which is the best possible for general case of sorting problem. Because to find complexity of 2-level cycle, you need to find complexity of subcycle and multiply them.

Of course, there exists an algorithm that can sort any array of numbers in $\mathcal{O}(n \log(n))$ time and $O(\log(n))$ space.

Comment: Actually I found a trick that we can convert the numbers to base $n$ which will allow us to achieve linear time complexity if my calculations are correct

Comment: You have cycles where you show complexities O(n) and O(count digits) inside it. If you multiply them, it won't be linear.

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: Line 6, you call that function $n$ times and itself it takes $O(log(n))$ time.

Comment: But we converted all numbers into base $n$ so it's $\Theta(6n)$ time because there're only 6 unique digit lengths

Comment: That will divide number into 5 parts and what? Computer still works with them as with binary strings.

Comment: But there can be only 6 digits in a number at most, which is a constant.

Comment: Why do you think that it's constant? If you'll take $n = 10^6$ you will receive a maximum number $n^5 = 10^{30}$ and it's length is 31 decimal digits (103 bits). If you'll convert that number into base $n$ it'll be represented as 5 24-bit strings.